# can we hide the native keyboard of ipad device on focus on textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cordova

I am working on phone Gap application in which i am using my custom jquery keyboard but when i focus on the input the native keyboard of device is open. I did't have knowledge of objective-C  so please can u help me to prevent the native keyboard on ios device when i click on the text field.

I am trying to do but it's work only for one time when i double click on the input field the application is crashed.

my code is..

```
// register for keyboard show event
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
     object:nil];
 // hiding UIWebviewAccessary
// http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self removeBar];
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjustFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

- (void)adjustFrame {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,0)"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```
// automatically close the keyboard on iOS
 document.activeElement.blur();
```

But i thinks u want to close keyboard when your input Focus().

also use ..

```
var hideKeyboard = function() {
document.activeElement.blur();
$("input").blur();
};
```

Comment: Yes it work but i want to hide the keyboard using native code because if we use blur() function than i am not able to open my custom keyboard because it's also open on focus event.